# How to use @ServiceConnection with GenericContainer and custom ConnectionDetails

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test, testcontainers, spring-boot-testcontainers

I am using new @ServiceConnection annotation to manage `KafkaContainer` in my tests and it works as expected - `KafkaContainerConnectionDetails` is used during auto configuration to override bootstrap servers property.

Now, i also want to use custom `GenericContainer` subclass i created - `SchemaRegistryContainer`.

I would also like to manage this container with `@ServiceConnection` annotation, but it crashes with `ConnectionDetailsNotFoundException: No ConnectionDetails found for source '@ServiceConnection source for Bean 'schemaRegistryContainer'`.

I would like have my own custom `ConnectionDetails` (or some alternative way) for this `@ServiceConnection`, so that i can modify application properties i need when `SchemaRegistryContainer` starts. In this specific case, i need to modify property `spring.kafka.consumer.properties.schema-registry-url` with url from container.

Is this there a way to achieve this with `@ServiceDefinition`?
I dont want to fall back to using static fields and `@DynamicPropertySource`.

My test configuration

```java
@TestConfiguration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class ContainerConfig {
    public static final DockerImageName DEFAULT_IMAGE_NAME = DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka");
    public static final String CONFLUENT_PLATFORM_VERSION = "7.4.1";

    @Bean
    @ServiceConnection
    KafkaContainer kafkaContainer() {
        return new KafkaContainer(DEFAULT_IMAGE_NAME.withTag(CONFLUENT_PLATFORM_VERSION));
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceConnection
    SchemaRegistryContainer schemaRegistryContainer(KafkaContainer kafkaContainer) {
        return new SchemaRegistryContainer(CONFLUENT_PLATFORM_VERSION, kafkaContainer);
    }
}
```

SchemaRegistryContainer:

```java
public class SchemaRegistryContainer extends GenericContainer<SchemaRegistryContainer> {

    private static final int PORT = 8081;

    public SchemaRegistryContainer(String confluentVersion, KafkaContainer kafka) {
        super("confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:" + confluentVersion);

        withExposedPorts(PORT);
        dependsOn(kafka);
        withEnv("SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS", kafka.getBootstrapServers());
    }

    public String getSchemaRegistryUrl() {
        return "http://" + getHost() + ":" + getMappedPort(PORT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out i was misunderstanding what `@ServiceConnection` was doing.
In fact, this annotation is not needed at all, if i dont have custom `ConnectionDetails` but i still can use container as @Bean.

For customizing properties after contaner starts, i used DynamicPropertyRegistry. This is in fact also mentioned in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.1.0/reference/htmlsingle/#features.testing.testcontainers.at-development-time.dynamic-properties

New code:

```java
    @Bean
    SchemaRegistryContainer schemaRegistryContainer(KafkaContainer kafkaContainer, DynamicPropertyRegistry dynamicPropertyRegistry) {
        SchemaRegistryContainer schemaRegistryContainer = new SchemaRegistryContainer(CONFLUENT_PLATFORM_VERSION, kafkaContainer);
        dynamicPropertyRegistry.add("spring.kafka.consumer.properties.schema.registry.url", schemaRegistryContainer::getTarget);
        dynamicPropertyRegistry.add("spring.kafka.producer.properties.schema.registry.url", schemaRegistryContainer::getTarget);
        return schemaRegistryContainer;
    }
```